# How can we use “launch Template” in elastic beanstalk using terraform?

Tags: terraform

I cannot find the option for launch template in elastic beanstalk terraform document. Is there any way to use

Answer (score 0):

You add a configuration settings to your `aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment` resource, similar to this example

```
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
    name      = "IamInstanceProfile"
    value     = aws_iam_instance_profile.example.name
  }
```

**UPDATE**
Regarding the template , you probably need a cascade of resources.

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "example" {
  #...
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "example" {
  #...
  launch_template {
    id      = "${aws_launch_template.example.id}"
    version = "$Latest"
  }
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "example" {
  #...
  autoscaling_groups = ["${aws_autoscaling_group.example.id}"]
}
```

Comment: You have used aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration i need to use launchtemplate but there is no any option for the same. let me know if you have any solution.